# Pass Parameter from One Arrow Function to Another?

Tags: javascript

I am using formik in Reactjs and there is an onSubmit method which has a setSubmitting paramater. I want to pass it down to my "then" method but not sure how to do this.

```
  onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting, setErrors }) => {

            setSubmitting(true);

            // how can I get away from doing this.
            const submitting = setSubmitting;

              ajaxMethod(values)
              .then(() => {
                submitting(false);  // how could I just call setSubmitting.             
              })
              .catch((error, ) => {

                submitting(false);
              });
          }}
```

edit

```
 <Formik
          initialValues={{
          }}
          validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
          })}
          onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting, setErrors }) => {
            setSubmitting(true);

            const submitting = setSubmitting;

            ajaxMethod(values)
              .then(() => {
                setSubmitting(false);
              })
              .catch((error, setSubmitting) => {
                setSubmitting(false);
              });
          }}
          render={props => (
            <Form autoComplete="off" id="record-payment-form">

            </Form>
          )}
        />


 ajaxMethod: flow(function*(formData) {

    })
```

Comment: Why not just call `setSubmitting(…)` directly?

Comment: `.catch((error, setSubmitting) =>` looks to be the culprit. That will "shadow" / replace the previous `setSubmitting` variable, and I don't think you want that here.

Comment: hmm, I added that because it was not working. Maybe I did something else wrong as now it all seems to work. Going to try a few more times.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need that local `submitting` variable at all. Just call `setSubmitting`:

```
(values, { setSubmitting, setErrors }) => {
    setSubmitting(true);

    ajaxMethod(values).then(() => {
        setSubmitting(false);
    }).catch((error) => {
        setSubmitting(false);
    });
}
```

Btw, you will probably want to use [`finally`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally) instead:

```
(values, { setSubmitting, setErrors }) => {
    setSubmitting(true);

    ajaxMethod(values).finally(() => {
        setSubmitting(false);
    });
}
```

Comment: well when I try to put it in the .then() or catch(). I get setSubmitting is not a function.

Comment: And with the extra variable it works? Weird. Is this your exact and whole code?

Comment: well it is just that section of the method. I can post the whole code

Comment: Yes please post the whole code. Probably you're overwriting it or something.